# How to cycle through multidimensional array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multidimensional-array

Im working on implementing searchkick in my project and got the search to work fine.  Now Im trying to implement a filter system and use the aggs to display the filter criteria.  The array that the aggs returns is a little complex for me and trying to figure out how to cycle through the specific parts.  Heres the aggs it returns:

> {"techniques"=>{"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0,
>   "sum_other_doc_count"=>0, "buckets"=>[{"key"=>"Frying",
>   "doc_count"=>1}, {"key"=>"Searing", "doc_count"=>1}]},
>   "ingredients"=>{"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0,
>   "sum_other_doc_count"=>0, "buckets"=>[{"key"=>"Furikake, for serving",
>   "doc_count"=>1}, {"key"=>"Kosher salt and ground black pepper",
>   "doc_count"=>1}, {"key"=>"Salmon fillets", "doc_count"=>1},
>   {"key"=>"avocado, diced", "doc_count"=>1}, {"key"=>"cooked white
>   rice", "doc_count"=>1}, {"key"=>"japanese cucumber", "doc_count"=>1},
>   {"key"=>"teriyaki sauce", "doc_count"=>1}, {"key"=>"to 8 scallions,
>   thinly sliced", "doc_count"=>1}, {"key"=>"vegetable oil",
>   "doc_count"=>1}]}, "cuisines"=>{"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0,
>   "sum_other_doc_count"=>0, "buckets"=>[{"key"=>"Asian",
>   "doc_count"=>1}, {"key"=>"Japanese", "doc_count"=>1}]}}

How would I write a do loop to cycle through just the cuisines part and pull out the individual names and counts from the buckets:

> "cuisines"=>{"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0,
>   "sum_other_doc_count"=>0, "buckets"=>[{"key"=>"Asian",
>   "doc_count"=>1}, {"key"=>"Japanese", "doc_count"=>1}]}}

So basically I want a list that would look like this:
Asian(1)
Japanese(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a hash with array elements. It depends what you exactly you want, but assuming you assigned it a variable `my_hash`, you can do this for example:

```
my_hash['cuisines']['buckets'].reduce('') do |r, h| 
  r += "#{h['key']} (#{h['doc_count']}) "
end
=> "Asian (1) Japanese (1) "
```